# How to cache static, dynamic response from a server ? Is it done through Nginx or I should do it on client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, caching

I have Nodejs running on a server and Nginx is configured to except requests and pass it to Nodejs application. All is good, everything is working.

It is a very basic nginx set up

```
http {

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
           gzip on;

           gzip_vary on;
           gzip_proxied any;
           gzip_comp_level 6;
           gzip_buffers 16 8k;
           gzip_http_version 1.1;
           gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

         server {
                 location /api {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
                        proxy_redirect off;
                }
        }

}
```

Now, I have a **route** on my backend that hosts images, as an example */api/image/3* or */api/image/19*. Now I'm thinking, how can I cache that response on a client side ?? Surely it wont change, *id* is rooted to an *image*. If user hit same route again I don't want request to be sent, I want get that binary, static image from a cache. Or maybe request is sent, but then on entry level it gets it from a cache, rather then do the whole job on getting that image. Cause I don't even know where do I start. Is it Nginx part of a job? Or is it done at Nodejs or even client side ?? And how to do it? Code would be appreciated, or at least a direction where do I have to dig to.

This route should stay protected as is in nodejs. Only authorized users can access.